# Java to C/C++, or at least get the Java converted code

Tags: java, c++, c

Are there any Java -> C/C++ Converters? Well I expect a no.

But I know Java works by converting the Java Byte Code, into code that the OS can understand using JIT. So is there any way to get this "converted code"?

Thanks.

---

Thanks to Baltasarq, who set me on the right course, I starting looking for Ahead of Time compilers, Amazingly, I found GCJ which is included in GCC (I think the latest?). It does exactly what I want. Take a Java file, turn it into an EXE. But, it needs 44 DLLS for a simple print "Hello World" app. Oh well :D

Comment: The Java language is simple, however it makes heavy use of libraries in the JDK and in third party applications.  This is where you will have to convert the code manually.

Answer (score 2):

> But I know Java works by converting the Java Byte Code, into code that the OS can understand using JIT. So is there any way to get this "converted code"?

You're talking about compiling code "ahead of time", or at least that's the name it receives in the Mono project (free implementation of .NET/C#). If you are interested on this, you could convert your code from Java to C# (which is at least easier than C++), and then take advantage of this feature. There is even a tool dedicated to this purpose: [mkbundle](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a way to get the JIT code issued ~ it is a runtime conversion that is done after like 1000 or 10,000 through some part of the code path - I am sure one can get this "converted code"! but what you are talking about is source-code and anyway the JVM runs on the byte code for 1000 or 10,000 before it even tries to bring int the JIT or can be made to run on byte code only

seems to me without knowing where your needs are I would think it faster to write the code by hand ~ if I need a short loop or something to explain something to some bode I can do it faster by hand than finding some tool to do it

there actually is a dumper that comes as part of a standard install ~ and I know it works because I have some code saved in source file comments where it did it

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any Java -> C/C++ Converters? Well I expect a no.

Well, there are some projects, but none I know of that are production-quality. Mostly they translate to C, as the additional features that C++ offers do not align very well with what Java does. A Google search will give you quite a few projects. Also see this question:

[Does a Java to C++ converter/tool exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556807/java-to-c-converter-tool)

> But I know Java works by converting the Java Byte Code, into code that
>   the OS can understand using JIT. So is there any way to get this
>   "converted code"?

No, not that I am aware of. You could theoretically take the HotSpot source code (it's available as part of OpenJDK), and insert logging statements to dump the generated machine code. I don't know if anyone has done that yet.